# Chinese verb 'to become'

Tags: grammar, mandarin, sentence-structure

I've found no leads as to this on the internet, and also have been unable to ask my teacher about this sentence struture. So, I hope this isn't a duplicate!

I was wondering, how do I say *become* in Mandarin?

For example:

*Since high school started, RE became boring.*

*If you don't exercise, you won't become fit.*

*If you keep practicing the piano, you'll become much more skilled.*

I don't know if I'm a total idiot, asking this question. I legitimately just can't find the answer, not even in my dictionary. No internet search has yielded any leads either.

Comment: jukuu has 100 example sentences for "become", "实用英汉词典＂：become v (1)变成（动），成为（动），当上（动）；变得（动）The exception has now become the rule.这例外现在已经成为规则了。His job is becoming increasingly difficult. 他的工作越来越困难了。She became the university president in 1986.她一九八六年当上了校长。

Comment: cf。英汉小词典 A junior English Chinese dictionary 商务印书馆 １９７７年•北京 become １。变成；成为；It has become much warmer, 天暖和得多了。China has ～ a socialist country with initial prosperity. 中国已成为一个初步繁荣的社会主义国家。How did you ～ acquainted with him? 你怎样和他认识的？

Answer (score 2):

For "become + adjective" it would be "變得+ adjective"

- 「自高校開學以來，RE 就**變得**沈悶 」 - "Since high school started, RE **became** boring."
- 「如果你不運動，你就不會**變得**健美 」 - "If you don't exercise, you won't **become** fit."
- 「如果你繼續練習鋼琴，你將會**變得**更有技巧 」 - "If you keep practicing the piano, you'll **become** much more skilled."

For " become + noun" it would be "成為 + noun"

- 「我想**成為**一個醫生 」 - "I want to **become** a doctor."
- 「她想**成為**偶像歌手 」 - "she wants to **become** an idol singer."

> Google Translate:
>
> 自高校开学以来，RE 就变得沉闷
>
> 如果你不运动，你就不会变得健美
>
> 如果你继续练习钢琴，你将会变得更有技巧
>
> 我想成为一个医生
>
> 她想成为偶像歌手

Comment: Would you be able to tell me the simplified characters?

Comment: @Lythric http://www.chinese-tools.com/tools/converter-tradsimp.html

Answer (score 0):

These three sentence can actually be translated in this way:

Since high school started, RE became boring.
（学校）开学后，RE就变得无聊。 (words in the parenthesises can be omitted. You don't have to specify it's high school here.)

If you don't exercise, you won't become fit.
如果你不运动，就不会有好身材。（for body shape）
or 如果你不锻炼，身体就不会好。(for health)

If you keep practicing the piano, you'll become much more skilled.
如果坚持练琴，你会弹得更好。
or 如果坚持练琴，你会更加出色。

The above translations would best suit the context of verbal Chinese. When speaking Chinese, you try to use simpler words and shorter sentences.

If you translate each word into corresponding Chinese word, the sentence would be verbose and sound awkward/weird to local people.